# No envía los datos de la constante definida en js al Php correspondiente

Tags: php, jquery, post

Tengo un pequeño formulario para agregar un cliente, lo recibo con JQuery y no tengo idea de como seguir...

```js
$('#agregar').submit(function(e){
      const dataAgregar = {
        nombre: $('#nombre').val(),
        apellido: $('#apellido').val(),
        dni: $('#dni').val()
    }
    console.log(dataAgregar);
    $.post('/autoparts_system/modulos/Clientes/cliente-add.php', {dataAgregar}, 
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
        fetchList();

        // Se resetea el formulario luego de haber enviado los datos
        $('#agregar').trigger('reset');
            
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" id="agregar">
   <h3>Ingrese los datos del cliente</h3>
   <p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Escriba su nombre: </label>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
      </label>
   </div>
   </p>    
   <p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Escriba su apellido </label>
      <input type="text" id="apellido" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
      </label>
   </div>
   </p>
   <p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Escriba su DNI:</label>
      <input type="text" id="dni" >
      </label>
   </div>
   </p>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php

require '../../php/conexion.php';

$nombre   = strtoupper($_POST['nombre']);
$apellido = strtoupper($_POST['apellido']);
$dni      = $_POST['dni'];


echo $nombre, $apellido;
?>
```

Al mostrar los datos en la Línea console.log(dataAgregar) después de definir la constante, veo en consola todos los datos introducidos al formulario
pero al correr el código en mi localhost el error que me lanza el Php es que no recibe los datos que envía... el `console.log(response)` que se encuentra dentro del método `$.post` me devuelve índice indefinido para todas las variables del Php!

Comment: Ese validador está obsoleto, no acepta código ES2015

Comment: Ah bien, disculpen mi ignorancia es que soy nueva en esto! me recomendas alguno para probar? @PabloLozano

Comment: Si usas un editor como Visual Studio Code, te indicará si tienes algo mal en la sintaxis. Pero no veo problemas por ese lado, creo que el problema está en que usas postData en lugar de dataAgregar (postData no parece estar declarado)

Comment: Si cierto! Pero eso fue a causa de que ya me había dado ese error de que no envía los datos al Php  por eso le cambie el nombre... @PabloLozano según lo que me decís, si uso VSC pero no me muestra ningún error de sintaxis!

Comment: Te explico los datos del formulario los muestro a través del console.log(dataAgregar) y me muestra los datos ingresados, el tema esta en que cuando mando esa variable al Php a través de $.post() no me envía nada y las variables del Php resultan indefinidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te explico a través de un ejemplo como se debe ejecutar

```js
$('#agregar').submit(function(e){
      //usa e.preventDefault() evita la accion del submit
      e.preventDefault()
      const dataAgregar = {
        nombre: $('#nombre').val(),
        apellido: $('#apellido').val(),
        dni: $('#dni').val()
    }
    console.log(dataAgregar);
    $.ajax({
            url: '/autoparts_system/modulos/Clientes/cliente-add.php',
            type: 'post',
          data: dataAgregar,
        beforeSend: function (){
            //opcional
        //antes de enviar puedes colocar un gif cargando o un  mensaje que diga espere...
        }

      }).done(function(data){
            console.log(response);
        fetchList();
        // Se resetea el formulario luego de haber enviado los datos
        $('#agregar').trigger('reset');
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //en caso de que haya un error muestras un mensaje con el error
        console.log(thrownError);
      })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" id="agregar">
   <h3>Ingrese los datos del cliente</h3>
   <p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Escriba su nombre: </label>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
      </label>
   </div>
   </p>    
   <p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Escriba su apellido </label>
      <input type="text" id="apellido" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
      </label>
   </div>
   </p>
   <p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Escriba su DNI:</label>
      <input type="text" id="dni" >
      </label>
   </div>
   </p>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Te dejo con comentarios la explicación del código.

Comment: Le cambie todo y funciona perfecto!  Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si bien la respuesta anterior es correcta, considera mandar todo tu formulario en un objeto `FormData` Esto mandara todo lo que tengas en tu formulario `id="agregar"` cabe mencionar que todos tus `inputs` le deberas agregar el atributo `name` ya que atraves de ese atributo `name` podras recibirlo con PHP ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" style="text-transform:uppercase;">
```

Entonces tu peticion quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#agregar").submit(function (e) {
  //usa e.preventDefault() evita la accion del submit
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: "URL A DONDE QUIERES MANDAR TU PETICION",
    method: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this), //THIS HACE REFERENCIA AL FORMULARIO #agregar
    cache: "false",
    beforeSend: function () {
      //PUEDES HACER ALGO ANTES DE QUE SE ENVIE TU PETICION
    },
    success: function (data) {
      // EN DATA VIENE LA INFO QUE TE RESPONDE EL SERVIDOR
    },
  });
});
```

Te dejo unos enlaces para que puedas comprender lo planteado:

[FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)